# Using getCov in R lavaan with an actual, large correlation matrix

Tags: r, matrix, memory-management, r-lavaan, factor-analysis

I’m looking to use lavaan confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) functionality with 120 indicators (variables) and about 400k respondents. This large sample size is causing memory issues in R. Usually I might just use a smaller batch of people, but I’m trying to replicate existing work. I’ve tried simply reading the correlation/covariance matrix into R and then doing CFA, but I’m having trouble with the getCov function. Every example I see involves manually writing an object that represents the set of correlations. However, that is not possible with a 120-by-120 matrix. I’ve tried generating a correlation matrix within R, and then reading that matrix into getCov, but am still getting a lot of errors. I imagine there is some way to format this, and I’ve tried several approaches (two below), to no avail.

Here is an example where I create a dataset of 120 variables. For the sake of ease, I set sample size to 1000. When I try to generate a correlation matrix and then use the getCov command, I get the following error:

“Error in lav_matrix_lower2full(x, diagonal = diagonal) : p == round(p, 0) is not TRUE”

```
set.seed(371)
df  <-   data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 1000, ncol = 120))
for (i in 1:120) {
  x <- runif(1000, min=1, max=7)
  df [, i] <- x
}
dim (df)

#getting correlations... I think getCov needs only one diagonal side#
cor.matrix <- round(cor(df),4)
upper<-cor.matrix
upper[upper.tri(cor.matrix)]<-NA
lower<-as.matrix (upper)

#try 1#
matrix <- getCov (x=lower, names = c('X1',  'X2',   'X3',   'X4',   'X5',   'X6',   'X7',   'X8',   'X9',   'X10',  'X11',  'X12',  'X13',  'X14',  'X15',  
                                     'X16', 'X17',  'X18',  'X19',  'X20',  'X21',  'X22',  'X23',  'X24',  'X25',  'X26',  'X27',  'X28',  
                                     'X29', 'X30',  'X31',  'X32',  'X33',  'X34',  'X35',  'X36',  'X37',  'X38',  'X39',  'X40',  'X41',  'X42',  'X43',  'X44',  'X45',  'X46',  
                                     'X47', 'X48',  'X49',  'X50',  'X51',  'X52',  'X53',  'X54',  'X55',  'X56',  'X57',  'X58',  'X59',  'X60',  'X61',  'X62',  'X63',  'X64',  
                                     'X65', 'X66',  'X67',  'X68',  'X69',  'X70',  'X71',  'X72',  'X73',  'X74',  'X75',  'X76',  'X77',  'X78',  'X79',  'X80',  'X81',  'X82',  
                                     'X83', 'X84',  'X85',  'X86',  'X87',  'X88',  'X89',  'X90',  'X91',  'X92',  'X93',  'X94',  'X95',  'X96',  'X97',  'X98',  'X99',  'X100', 
                                     'X101',    'X102', 'X103', 'X104', 'X105', 'X106', 'X107', 'X108', 'X109', 'X110', 'X111', 'X112', 'X113', 'X114', 'X115', 'X116', 'X117', 'X118', 
                                     'X119',    'X120'))
#try 2#
lower <- format_csv (as.data.frame(lower), col_names=FALSE)
matrix <- getCov (x=lower, names = c('X1',  'X2',   'X3',   'X4',   'X5',   'X6',   'X7',   'X8',   'X9',   'X10',  'X11',  'X12',  'X13',  'X14',  'X15',  
                                         'X16', 'X17',  'X18',  'X19',  'X20',  'X21',  'X22',  'X23',  'X24',  'X25',  'X26',  'X27',  'X28',  
                                         'X29', 'X30',  'X31',  'X32',  'X33',  'X34',  'X35',  'X36',  'X37',  'X38',  'X39',  'X40',  'X41',  'X42',  'X43',  'X44',  'X45',  'X46',  
                                         'X47', 'X48',  'X49',  'X50',  'X51',  'X52',  'X53',  'X54',  'X55',  'X56',  'X57',  'X58',  'X59',  'X60',  'X61',  'X62',  'X63',  'X64',  
                                         'X65', 'X66',  'X67',  'X68',  'X69',  'X70',  'X71',  'X72',  'X73',  'X74',  'X75',  'X76',  'X77',  'X78',  'X79',  'X80',  'X81',  'X82',  
                                         'X83', 'X84',  'X85',  'X86',  'X87',  'X88',  'X89',  'X90',  'X91',  'X92',  'X93',  'X94',  'X95',  'X96',  'X97',  'X98',  'X99',  'X100', 
                                         'X101',    'X102', 'X103', 'X104', 'X105', 'X106', 'X107', 'X108', 'X109', 'X110', 'X111', 'X112', 'X113', 'X114', 'X115', 'X116', 'X117', 'X118', 
                                         'X119',    'X120'))
```